# Regex for valid directory path

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create regex to check against a valid directory prefix, where directory names must not be empty, and can contain any alphabet characters [a-zA-Z] and any numbers [0-9]. They can also contain dashes (-) and underscores (_) but no other special characters. A directory prefix can contain any number of forward slashes (/), and a valid path must not end with a forward slash (/) either.

Valid examples would be:

- `/abc/def`
- `/hello_123/world-456`
- `/` (a special case where a single forward slash is allowed)

Invalid examples would be:

- `/abc/def/`
- `/abc//def`
- `//`
- `abc/def`
- `/abc/def/file.txt`

So far I have `^(\/+(?!\/))[A-Za-z0-9\/\-_]+$` but it's not checking against what would be empty directory names (e.g. two forward slashed one after the other `/abc//def`), or path's ending with a slash (e.g. `/hello_123/world-456/`)

Comment: Tangentially, slash is not a regex metacharacter, and doesn't need backslash escaping in many regex dialects. In violation of the [tag:regex] tag guidance, your question fails to reveal which regex tool you need help with.

Comment: `/+` will match ALL slashes, so `(?!\/)` will always be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose [`^((/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)+|/)$`](https://regex101.com/r/dQ328B/1). Explanation:

- `^` and `$`: Match the entire string/line
- `(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)+`: One or more directories, starting with slash, separated by slashes; each directory must consist of one or more characters of your charset
- `(...)+|/`: Explicitly allow just a single slash

You might want to use noncapturing groups `(?:...)` here: `^(?:(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)+|/)$`. If you only use regex match "testing" this won't matter though.

Side note: Do you want to allow directory names to start with `-`, `_` or a number? This is fairly unusual for names in most naming schemes. You might want to use `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_]*` to require a leading letter.